# Kafka Stream with Avro in JAVA , schema.registry.url" which has no default value

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-schema-registry

I have the following configuration for my Kafka Stream application

```
    Properties config = new Properties();
    config.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG,this.applicaionId);
    config.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,svrConfig.getBootstrapServers());
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

    // we disable the cache to demonstrate all the "steps" involved in the transformation - not recommended in prod
    config.put(StreamsConfig.CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG, svrConfig.getCacheMaxBytesBufferingConfig());

    // Exactly once processing!!
    config.put(StreamsConfig.PROCESSING_GUARANTEE_CONFIG, StreamsConfig.EXACTLY_ONCE);
    config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG,SpecificAvroSerde.class);
    config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG,SpecificAvroSerde.class);
    config.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG,"http://localhost:8081");
```

And I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" io.confluent.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration "schema.registry.url" which has no default value.
at io.confluent.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:243)
at io.confluent.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:78)
at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.<init>(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.java:100)
at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.<init>(KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.java:32)
at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.configure(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:48)
at io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerializer.configure(SpecificAvroSerializer.java:58)
at io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde.configure(SpecificAvroSerde.java:107)
```

I have tried to replace the line

```
config.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG,"http://localhost:8081");
```

with

```
config.put("schema.registry.url","http://localhost:8081");
```

but with the same error

I have followed the instruction from [this url](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/datatypes.html) when preparing my Stream application.

Any suggestion?

Comment: From the linked example, where is your `Collections.singletonMap`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have keys and values in Avro format the following lines should do the trick for you,

```
config.put("key.converter.schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081");  
config.put("value.converter.schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081");
```

If this doesn't seem to work you can override `Serdes` explicitly. For example, if you have Avro keys:

```
final Map<String, String> serdeConfig = Collections.singletonMap("schema.registry.url",
                                                                 "http://localhost:8081");
final Serde<GenericRecord> keyGenericAvroSerde = new GenericAvroSerde();
keyGenericAvroSerde.configure(serdeConfig, true); // true for record keys
final Serde<GenericRecord> valueGenericAvroSerde = new GenericAvroSerde();
valueGenericAvroSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false); // false for record values

StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
KStream<GenericRecord, GenericRecord> textLines =
builder.stream(keyGenericAvroSerde, valueGenericAvroSerde, "my-avro-topic");
// Do whatever you like
```

Comment: Thanks so much Giorgos. Turn out I add the line "final Map<String, String> serdeConfig = Collections.singletonMap("schema.registry.url",
"http://localhost:8081");" and everything works fine. I was thinking this line is only an optional setting to be run but turn out it seems this is a must~

Comment: Follow up: Configs from `StreamConfig` are only passed to all Serdes KafkaStreams creates internally. For you case, you create the Serdes in your code, and thus it's your responsibility to provide the correct configuration. Cf. https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/datatypes.html#avro

Comment: Do anyone know how to configure the same in spring boot application? maybe directly via `application.yml`?

Comment: @Naveen check my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/68574923/1128216

Comment: Why are you using Kafka Connect converter properties for Kafka Streams?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using an `application.yml` you can set the property like:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    properties:
      schema.registry.url: your-schema-registy-url
    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: latest
      group-id: simple-consumer
```

I found it in a tutorial from the [confluent blog](https://www.confluent.io/blog/schema-registry-avro-in-spring-boot-application-tutorial/)

Comment: It logs a warning `The configuration 'schema.registry.url' was supplied but isn't a known config.`
There's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66355989/1128216) saying that the warning goes away by changing the position of the property (placing it after the `producer` property) That suggestion doesn't work for me.

Comment: The warning is because AdminClient config doesn't know about that property. You can move it under `consumer.properties` to silence that

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the answer is outdated.
It worked for me using this code snippet (the example here is just piping one topic to another without any change).

```
    final Map<String, String> serdeConfig = Collections.singletonMap(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG,"http://localhost:8081");
    final Serde<GenericRecord> keyGenericAvroSerde = new GenericAvroSerde();
    keyGenericAvroSerde.configure(serdeConfig, true); // true for record keys
    final Serde<GenericRecord> valueGenericAvroSerde = new GenericAvroSerde();
    valueGenericAvroSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false); // false for record values

    StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

    builder.stream("my-avro-topic",Consumed.with(keyGenericAvroSerde, valueGenericAvroSerde))
                .peek((k, v) -> log.info("Processed a new record")).to(outputTopic,Produced.with(keyGenericAvroSerde, valueGenericAvroSerde));
```

Comment: This seems to duplicate the bottom half of the accepted answer. If you're saying the Consumed / Produced objects are needed, better to edit / comment the post